# Xcode shows same function multiple times

Tags: xcode, swift

You can see these same suggestions. Do you know why or when it is happening? Because, it is not like this always.

Examples:

[image: xcode duplicate functions 1]
[image: xcode duplicate functions 2]

Answer (score 0):

this behavior appears if you have more than one XCode versions (maybe you have a beta version, as well) on your mac. Just download new content (simulators, documentation, etc...) from one single source.
Hope this answer helped you....
Regards, Alex

Comment: I don't have any other versions but I upgraded from old version to xcode 7.1 from App Store when it released. Maybe MacOS keeps some old libraries. I can try to find duplicated libs. Thanks :)

Comment: No, I am still using like that. It's a secret between my xcode and me :)

Comment: :) haha, I'll tell you if my colleague fixed his secret ;)